# How to detect multiple objects from image in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a newbie in `tensorflow`. I have gone through a tensorflow tutorial of Datacamp, which is [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tensorflow-tutorial) and become able to recognize 3 different class of objects from my test data with accuracy of 65%.

It only recognizes the objects from the image which contains only 1 object, where I want to detect multiple objects from a background image which may contain more than one object. So how to build a model which can detect several objects from image.

I am using TensorFlow-CPU.

To make it easy to understand, I include the codes below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage import transform
from skimage import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def load_data(data_dir):
    # Get all subdirectories of data_dir. Each represents a label.
    directories = [d for d in os.listdir(data_dir) 
                   if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_dir, d))]
    # Loop through the label directories and collect the data in
    # two lists, labels and images.
    labels = []
    images = []
    for d in directories:
        label_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, d)
        file_names = [os.path.join(label_dir, f) 
                      for f in os.listdir(label_dir) 
                      if f.endswith(".jpg")]
        for f in file_names:
            images.append(data.imread(f))
            labels.append(int(d))
    return images, labels

ROOT_PATH = "C:/...../ImageClasses/"
train_data_dir = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "TrainImages")
test_data_dir = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "TestImages")

images, labels = load_data(train_data_dir)

images_array = np.array(images)
labels_array = np.array(labels)

# Print the `images` dimensions
print(images_array.ndim)

# Print the number of `images`'s elements
print(images_array.size)

# Print the first instance of `images`
images_array[0]

# Print the `labels` dimensions
print(labels_array.ndim)

# Print the number of `labels`'s elements
print(labels_array.size)

# Count the number of labels
print(len(set(labels_array)))

# Make a histogram with 62 bins of the `labels` data
plt.hist(labels, 62)

# Show the plot
plt.show()

# Determine the (random) indexes of the images that you want to see 
traffic_signs = [300, 250, 1150, 1230]

# Fill out the subplots with the random images that you defined 
for i in range(len(traffic_signs)):
    plt.subplot(1, 4, i+1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(images[traffic_signs[i]])
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)

plt.show()

# Determine the (random) indexes of the images
traffic_signs = [300, 225, 365, 400]

# Fill out the subplots with the random images and add shape, min and max values
for i in range(len(traffic_signs)):
    plt.subplot(1, 4, i+1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(images[traffic_signs[i]])
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)
    plt.show()
    print("shape: {0}, min: {1}, max: {2}".format(images[traffic_signs[i]].shape, 
                                                  images[traffic_signs[i]].min(), 
                                                  images[traffic_signs[i]].max()))

# Resize images
images32 = [transform.resize(image, (28, 28)) for image in images]
images32 = np.array(images32)

#Image Conversion to Grayscale
images32 = rgb2gray(np.array(images32))

for i in range(len(traffic_signs)):
    plt.subplot(1, 4, i+1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(images32[traffic_signs[i]], cmap="gray")
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)

plt.show()

print(images32.shape)

x = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None, 28, 28])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int32, shape = [None])
images_flat = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(x)
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(images_flat, 3, tf.nn.relu)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y, logits = logits))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)
correct_pred = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

print("images_flat: ", images_flat)
print("logits: ", logits)
print("loss: ", loss)
print("predicted_labels: ", correct_pred)

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(201):
        print('EPOCH', i)
        _, accuracy_val = sess.run([train_op, accuracy], feed_dict={x: images32, y: labels})
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print("Loss: ", loss)
        print('DONE WITH EPOCH')

# Load the test data
test_images, test_labels = load_data(test_data_dir)

# Transform the images to 28 by 28 pixels
test_images28 = [transform.resize(image, (28, 28)) for image in test_images]

# Convert to grayscale
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
test_images28 = rgb2gray(np.array(test_images28))

# Run predictions against the full test set.
predicted = sess.run([correct_pred], feed_dict={x: test_images28})[0]

# Calculate correct matches 
match_count = sum([int(y == y_) for y, y_ in zip(test_labels, predicted)])

# Calculate the accuracy
accuracy = match_count / len(test_labels)

# Print the accuracy
print("Accuracy: {:.3f}".format(accuracy))

sess.close()
```

Comment: Are you using a pre-trained model, if so which one? If custom trained, on how many classes is your model trained upon?

Comment: Not pre-trained. I trained the model for 3 main classes.